# Create a dummy java.net.http.HttpResponse without making an HTTP request

Tags: java, null, httpresponse, java-11

I have a method that returns an `java.net.http.HttpResponse` object or null. This means every place I call this method I need to do a nullcheck before checking what the response is.

i.e today I have:

```
public HttpResponse<String> makeRequest(HttpRequest request) {
    if (condition) {
        return client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }
    return null; // Want to change this to a mock instance
}
```

To prevent needless null checking in every place where I call this method, I wanted to create a mock `java.net.http.HttpResponse` instance so I can pass that instead of null. Ideally, maybe a request with `statuscode=500` and some Json entity as the body. How can I create a  `HttpResponse` instance without making an actual HTTP request?

I can't create a `HttpResponse` instance or `HttpResponseImpl` directly because both are package-protected classes. So unsure how to proceed. This method is used across different places, so fixing this removes the need to null-check in every place.

Help much appreciated

Comment: The interface `java.net.http.HttpResponse` is public. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to use `HttpResponse` in your code. Either create your own class that implements that interface or find some library that already did that.

Comment: as an alternate, are you sure you don't want to change the return type to `Optional<HttpResponse<String>>`?

Comment: I would still have to check the Optional in every place where the method is used. I want to avoid that,

Answer (score 0):

To help others. As mentioned by @fish, We can create a class that implements HttpResponse in which we can customize a response.

Example:

```
public HttpResponse<String> makeRequest(HttpRequest request)  {
    HttpResponse<String> response;
    try {
        response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        response = new HttpErrorResponse(e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}




import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpHeaders;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.Optional;

public class HttpErrorResponse implements HttpResponse {

    private int code = 500;
    private String message;

    public HttpErrorResponse() {
        this.message = "Opps! Error undefine";
    }

    public HttpErrorResponse(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public HttpErrorResponse(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public int statusCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpRequest request() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<HttpResponse> previousResponse() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public HttpHeaders headers() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object body() {
        return getJsonBody();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<SSLSession> sslSession() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private String getJsonBody(){
        return "{\n" +
                "\"status\": \"ERROR_RESPONSE\",\n" +
                "\"message\": \""+this.message+"\"\n" +
                "}";
    }
}
```